# React native sort by nested parameter(with nullable case)

Tags: react-native, sorting

I have some trouble with my sort, it's not working at all.

Assume I have a model like this:

```
{
  ServiceId: fgvGs6KWVEWWGt0YfTR6MA,
  RoomId: BHuGrnIXlkOnBi4IaXZK9w,
  UserStatus: 100,
  UserType: 3000,
  RoomType: 200,
  RoomName: test,
  Config: {
    OrderType: 0,
    HasPwd: false,
    DisallowCall: false
  },
  MsgInfo: {
    LastReadInfo: {
      Id: RXnyxcR9rUGAatL_wm_Dqg,
      Index: 149,
      ReadDate: 1659370675532
    }
  },
  LastMsg: {
    Preview: {
      Text: z,
      Avatar: ...,
      ChatMsgType: 1000,
      Type: 1,
      SenderServiceId: 37XApWVypU-iMdQByTXUJw
    },
    CIndex: 150,
    Status: 100,
    SendDate: 1659413290589,
    SenderId: d3f0c3cd-f363-4303-8761-8e190f054be3,
    Id: RXnyxcR9rUGAatL_wm_Dqg
  },
  CreateDate: 1657104351206
}
```

the purpose is sort by 3 conditions:

1. OrderType - can be null (It's mean favorite's room, so it's need to be display in top)
2. SendDate - can be null (It's message send time)
3. CreateDate - not null (When room created, no message and no OrderType, so this can be sort by CreateDate)

My goal is:
When rooms has Favorite(1) -> all those room will be in top and sorted using SendDate
If not(2), those room were below (1) then sorted by SendDate
Other case will sorted by CreateDate

My worked case is only for (2), when applied (1) (3), this display wrong always, can someone help? Thanks so much

Here is my code( not working)

```
if(r1.SendDate == null){
            r1['SendDate'] = r1.CreateDate
        }
        if(r2.SendDate == null){
            r2['SendDate'] = r2.CreateDate
        }

        if(r1.Config?.OrderType != null && r2.Config?.OrderType != null){
            return r2.LastMsg?.SendDate - r1.LastMsg?.SendDate
        }else if(r1.Config?.OrderType == null && r2.Config?.OrderType != null){
            return true
        }else if(r1.Config?.OrderType != null && r2.Config?.OrderType == null){
            return false
        }else{
            return r2.LastMsg?.SendDate - r1.LastMsg?.SendDate
        }
```

im tried to using other solution:

```
return noneHidedRoom.sort(
        firstBy(function (r1, r2) { 
            if(r1.Config == null && r2.Config != null) return 1
            else if(r1.Config != null && r2.Config == null) return -1
            else if(r1.Config != null && r2.Config != null) return r2.Config.OrderType - r1.Config.OrderType
            else if(r1.Config == null && r2.Config == null) return 0
        })
        .thenBy(function (r1, r2) {
            if(r1.LastMsg == null && r2.LastMsg != null) return 1
            else if(r1.LastMsg != null && r2.LastMsg == null) return -1
            else if(r1.LastMsg == null && r2.LastMsg == null) return 0
            return r2.LastMsg.SendDate - r1.LastMsg.SendDate
         })
        .thenBy('CreateDate', 'desc')
    )
```

But still not working, only case(1) work, other failed

Comment: can you post this on expo snack? add dummy data there. ill check @famfamfam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. split your array into two arrays, one for orderType not null and one for orderType  null
2. sort the first array by orderType
3. split the second array (orderType null) into two arrays, one for sendDate null and one for sendDate not null
4. sort the  array which contains item with sendDate not null by sendDate
5. sort the  array which contains item with sendDate null by createDate
   so now you have 3 arrays sorted :

- firstArray for orderType not null
- secondArray one for orderType null and sendDate not null
- thirdArray one for sendDate null

6. merge the three arrays into one array [...firstArray, ...secondArray, ...thirdArray].

code:

```
const data =[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
const {orderTypeArr,notOrderTypeArr}= data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.Config.OrderType=== null ? 'orderTypeArr' : 'notOrderTypeArr'].push(curr);
  return acc;
 }, { orderTypeArr: [], notOrderTypeArr: [] })

const sortedByOrderType = orderTypeArr.sort((a,b) => a.Config.OrderType - b.Config.OrderType);
 const {notSendDateArr,sendDateArr} = notOrderTypeArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.LastMsg.SendDate === null ? 'notSendDateArr' : 'sendDateArr'].push(curr);
  return acc;
  }, { notSendDateArr: [], sendDateArr: [] })

const sortedBySendDate = sendDateArr.sort((a,b) => a.LastMsg.SendDate - b.LastMsg.SendDate);
const sortedByCreateDate = notSendDateArr.sort((a,b) => a.CreateDate - b.CreateDate);
const sortedArr = [...sortedByOrderType,...sortedBySendDate,...sortedByCreateDate ];
console.log(sortedArr); //sorted array as you want.
```